# Javascript - Concat/update arrays of dictionaries based on key-value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays of dictionaries, each having a varied number of objects

Array 1

```
[
  { id: "1", color: "orange" },
  { id: "2", color: "red" },
]
```

Array 2

```
[
  { id: "1", color: "pink" },
  { id: "3", color: "yellow" },
  { id: "4", color: "blue" },
]
```

I want the two to be combined so that objects with new ids from Array2 are added to Array1 (e.g. id=3,4) and objects with existing keys are replaced (e.g. id=1). So the final output would be

```
[
  { id: "1", color: "pink" },
  { id: "2", color: "red" },
  { id: "3", color: "yellow" },
  { id: "4", color: "blue" },
]
```

The only thing I can think of doing is running nested for loops - which is probably the worst way to approach this. What would be the most effective way to achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge those array then filter out the records having duplicate ids and then sort it. I suppose this is what you need:

```js
var arr2=[{"id":"1","color":"pink"}, {"id":"3","color":"yellow"},{"id":"4","color":"blue"}];

var arr1=[{"id":"1","color":"orange"}, {"id":"2","color":"red"}];

var result = [...arr2,...arr1].filter((val, i, self)=>self.findIndex(k=>k.id==val.id)==i).sort((a,b)=>a.id-b.id);

console.log(result);
```

One approach could be this as well(by using `Map`):

```js
var arr2=[{"id":"1","color":"pink"}, {"id":"3","color":"yellow"},{"id":"4","color":"blue"}];

var arr1=[{"id":"1","color":"orange"}, {"id":"2","color":"red"}];

var result = [...new Map([...arr1,...arr2].map(k=>[k.id,k])).values()];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: The ids are string values and they might not always be needed in a sorted format.

Comment: @user3539959 if you don't need sort, then you can omit that part.

Comment: But then that would give me the result in order 1,3,4,2. I need it in the order 1,2,3,4 (i.e. elements from arr1 come first and then the elements from arr2)

Comment: @user3539959 I have added another version, have a look

Comment: Yep, I think the map should do it. Trying out now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

concat, reduce, and values

```js
var a = [
  { id: "1", color: "orange" },
  { id: "2", color: "red" },
]
var b = [
  { id: "1", color: "pink" },
  { id: "3", color: "yellow" },
  { id: "4", color: "blue" },
]
    
var result = Object.values(a.concat(b).reduce((o, item) => (o[item.id] = item, o), {}))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say a simple `for..loop` is much better for this.

```js
var arr1 = [
  { id: "1", color: "orange" },
  { id: "2", color: "red" },
]
var arr2 = [
  { id: "1", color: "pink" },
  { id: "3", color: "yellow" },
  { id: "4", color: "blue" },
]
var ids = arr2.map(i => i.id);

for(let i of arr1){
  if(!ids.includes(i.id)){
     arr2.push(i)
  }
}

console.log(arr2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Push elements from array, then filter by id and sort by id

```js
for(let obj of arr1){
  arr2.push(obj);
}

var newArr = arr2.filter((x, index, self) =>
  index === self.findIndex((t) => (
    t.id === x.id)));     //Filter by id

function compare(a, b) {
  if ( a.id < b.id ){
    return -1;
  }
  if ( a.id > b.id ){
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

var output = newArr.sort(compare); // Sort by id

console.log(output);
```